# Why the batch "call" command is not executed in Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following two batch files, `bat1.bat` calls `bat2.bat`.

bat1.bat:

```
@echo off
echo bat1 start >> C:\battest\log.log
call bat2.bat
echo bat1 end >> C:\battest\log.log
```

bat2.bat:

```
@echo off
echo bat2 >> C:\battest\log.log
```

When I run `bat1.bat` directly in command line, the output is as expected as below:

```
bat1 start 
bat2 
bat1 end
```

However, when I create a task in Windows Task Scheduler to run bat1.bat, I only get this:

```
bat1 start 
bat1 end
```

It seems the `call bat2.bat` has no effect. Why?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out.

When I run it directly in command line, the working directory is `C:\battest`.

However, when it is executed by Windows Task Scheduler, the working directory is `C:\windows\system32`, but there isn't the file `bat2.bat`.

I need to specify the full path of `bat2.bat` as below:

```
call C:\battest\bat2.bat
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yes, that's better. I will do that.